# Index (x_i) with two rows in latex

Tags: matrices, notation

I have following problem in latex formatting:

I want to write for a matrix : $ (a_{ij})_{\underset{j=1,\ldots , n}{i=1,\ldots ,m}} $ but I want the $i=\ldots$ and $j=\ldots$ to be the same size... 
Does anyone know a command to do that?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You should ask this question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The short answer is to use \substack, but you'll probably get better replies on the tex stackexchange board (which is a useful place in general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/expression-under-summation-on-multiple-lines

$(a_{ij})_{\substack{j=1, \cdots , n \\ i=1, \cdots , m}}$

```
 (a_{ij})_{\substack{j=1, \cdots , n \\ i=1, \cdots , m}}
```